# LWT installation failed using OPAM

Tags: opam, ocaml-lwt, lwt, oracle-opam

LWT installation failed using OPAM on Ubuntu

**Server Information -**

> Distributor ID: Ubuntu,
>   Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4, 
>   LTS Release: 18.04,
>   Codename: bionic

**Steps I followed -**

```
opam list -a         # List the available packages
opam install lwt     # Install LWT
opam update          # Update the package list
...
opam upgrade         # Upgrade the installed packages to their latest version
```

**Error I got -**

=-=- Error report -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
The following actions were aborted
  ∗  install lwt       4.1.0
  ∗  install ocamlfind 1.8.0
The following actions failed
  ∗  install conf-m4 1
No changes have been performed
```

I even tried `opam depext conf-m4.1` but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

**After following these -**

```
opam depext conf-m4.1

sudo opam install lwt
```

the problem is solved - but sudo is not recommended.